# php artisan make:controller throws: method controller doesnt exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to create a controller on an Homestead install for Laravel.
If I try:

```
php artisan make:controller test
```

I get

```
[BadMethodCallException]           
Method controller does not exist.
```

php version is 7, php artisan --version = 5.3

Answer (score 0):

oh just writing the question I discovered an error in routes.php.
Corrected the error now everything is fine...